# I want to join a server to a domain, I come back to you to ask if the opening ports 445 and 389 is necessary

Tags: active-directory

I want to join a server to a domain, I come back to you to ask if the opening ports 445 and 389 is necessary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes - ports 389 and 445 are required, as well as a number of other ports.  A note on Port 636:  that's the secure LDAP port - a domain-joining client cannot use this port when joining the domain because the client won't be able to trust the DC's SSL certificate until after it is already joined to the domain.  [Active Directory and Active Directory Domain Services Port Requirements](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd772723(WS.10).aspx)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, another question please,  can I force the server to join the domain with port 636 LDAPs and disable port 445 and 389?

Comment: That won't work; the client won't be able to trust the DC certificate before it is joined to the domain.  I will amend my answer to include this new question you asked.

Comment: Thanks for your reply

Comment: And what I can disable port 445 after joining server to domain ?

Comment: If you disable port 445 you will lose the ability to do CIFS / SMB file sharing over TCP/IP.